# NullPointerException in Google Play Services When Calling play() on RemotePlaybackClient

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast

[This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaRouter/RemotePlayback) of mine used to work just fine.

Somewhere in the past few months, though, Google updated Google Play Services (and Chromecast itself), and now when I call `play()` on `RemotePlaybackClient` for the Chromecast, Google Play Services itself crashes with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.gms.cast.media.aq.a(SourceFile:96)
        at com.google.android.gms.cast.media.n.i(SourceFile:1856)
        at com.google.android.gms.cast.media.u.run(SourceFile:2092)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note that the `play()` call itself has the desired effect, in that the Chromecast plays the media. But sometime after it calls the `ItemActionCallback` with `onResult()`, the aforementioned crash in Google PLay Services occurs. That, in turn, causes the connection to the Chromecast to collapse, so my `MediaRouteActionProvider` vanishes and I have to re-run my app to connect again, despite the Chromecast actually playing the media that I requested.

I have tested this with two devices (Nexus 4 and Galaxy Nexus) with the same results.

I have even created a new app, trying to just show an image (instead of play a movie, as with the original sample), and I get the same crash.

Has anyone seen this and found some workaround/fix/whatever?

Comment: What version of Google Play Services is on your devices?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: `version 6.1.88 (1557022-036)` on the Nexus 4, which I happen to have handy right at this moment. If you need the Galaxy Nexus one, let me know.

Comment: That awkward moment When @Commonsware got a crash :D and He Can't solve it... :)

Comment: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/commits/master FWIW - google  CC samples source get upd when libs r revise. This CC example which u dont use so big deal. I hav use this for CC apps over almost 2 years. My android, CC app  periodically break for no apparent reason. In which case, I go back to git n rePULL , Merge the project that was originally clone for my work and voila - mysterious bugs gone with new merged code. Merge can be somewhat involve has been worth effort because merge always solv bug. In general, that may be a reason to make use of the CC samples available.

Comment: @RobertRowntree: I am using `RemotePlaybackClient`. I have zero interest in the Cast SDK. Thanks, though!

Comment: If you can produce a short test case that exhibits the issue, we can take a look and address the issue if there is something on the Play Services side. In that case, please open a ticket on our issue tracker with your sample/test.

Comment: @AliNaddaf: What is "our issue tracker"? I am not aware that Play Services has an issue tracker, and http://b.android.com rejects all Play Services-related questions. BTW, I updated my sample (linked to in the question) to use `21.0.0` of `mediarouter-v7` (and `appcompat-v7`), and the problem persists. Thanks!

Comment: The stacktrace you are showing seems to be happening in the cast portion of play services and as such, you can open a ticket on our Cast SDK tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list). We would need a test case that can exhibit the issue so we can address it properly.

Comment: @AliNaddaf: Filed as https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=434 -- thanks!

Comment: The next version of Google Play Services includes a fix for this issue.

Comment: @AliNaddaf: I can confirm that the bug is now fixed, and my sample works again. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment chain, this was caused by a bug in Google Play Services, which is now fixed. Many thanks to Ali Naddaf for his assistance!

Answer (score -1):

Something with your video is causing GMS to crash. I ran into the same issue with your sample app. I changed your video to point to: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4 and it worked.

Comment: I get the same crash with your URL. Thanks, though!