# Google Play Services NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services

I know about java.lang.NullPointerException, but I got the following error from TestFairy the application that client already using: any one who face this problem please let me know how may I resolved this issue and why this issue generate,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  at
android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions(UserManager.java:614)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzah(Unknown
Source)     at
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzj(Unknown
Source)     at
com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zzj(Unknown
Source)     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzll.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli.zzoe(Unknown Source)    at
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown
Source)     at
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli$2.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown
Source)     at
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown
Source)     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)    at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899220/nullpointerexception-in-google-play-services-when-calling-play-on-remoteplayba

Comment: I see the same problem. 
It seems to correlate with Google Maps and Samsung Devices, at least I have only reports from Samsung SM-G800F devices running 4.4.2.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing this problem too but running Robolectric tests.. have you solved it?

Comment: Solved in Robolectric tests by creating a custom Robolectric Shadow

Comment: I got the same in Samsung running 4.3